# Python программа, собранная nuitka крашит на windows 7

Tags: python, nuitka

Написал программу, протестил, работает. Собрал через nuitka в один файл, на windows 10 работает отлично. Запускаю на windows 7 - пишет мол "программа не отвечает" и намертво зависает. Никаких сторонних модулей не использовал, компилировал вот такой командой - `nuitka --standalone --output-dir=deploy-nui --onefile --windows-product-version=1.0.0 --windows-company-name=astgasd --plugin-enable=tk-inter myscript.py`.
На всякий скачал на второй комп python, но это не помогло (а по сути и не могло помочь).
Извиняюсь за такое неподробное объяснение ситуации, но, честно говоря, я не знаю, что я могу ещё прикрепить, использую nuitka впервые, возможно кто-то связывался с этим.

Comment: Если у вас на компьютере, который выполнял компиляцию, установлен python 3.9, то скорее всего причина в этом. С версии 3.9, python не поддерживает windows 7. Попробуйте установить на ПК python 3.8 скомпилировать и потом проверить на семёрке.

Comment: @leach спасибо)